# json encode arabic issue

Tags: php, mysql, json, arabic

When writing json containing Arabic characters, they appear as question marks.

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db);    

$q = mysqli_query($con,'select `product_id`, `product_name`, `sku`, `price`, `final_price`, `minimal_price`, `special_price`, `image`, `small_image`, `thumb_image`, `short_description`, `href`, `is_favorite`, `category_name` from   products_uae_ar');
mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($con, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

print_r( json_encode($output));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the complete solution but you should tell the connection you want to use UTF-8 before issuing a query

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db);
mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($con, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8mb4');

$q = mysqli_query($con,'select `product_id`, `product_name`, `sku`, 
                           `price`, `final_price`, `minimal_price`, 
                           `special_price`, `image`, `small_image`, 
                           `thumb_image`, `short_description`, `href`, 
                           `is_favorite`, `category_name` 
                        from   products_uae_ar');

print_r( json_encode($output));
```

It would also be a good idea to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the data is in utf-8 try this.

```
$arr = array_map('utf8_encode', $arr);
$json = json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like

```
json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo json_encode($a,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Please describe, what did you change and why, to help others understand the problem and this answer